# Why does my top right search in Firefox sometimes switch from LTR to RTL

Tags: firefox

I assume it is a combination of keyboard buttons but I don't which ones and it is annoying because I have to open and close Firefox to get it back to LTR

Comment: I get this in Gmail chat too sometimes. Weird.

Comment: @Bill, ya I've gotten it in other places but whenever I refresh the page or whatever it reverts back, I can't refresh the top search without cycling the firefox instance

Comment: Uhhh LTR, RTL?!? What are you talking about? Edit: Ahhh! Left-to-Right and Right-to-Left!

Comment: Is this only in Firefox? It seems related with switching keyboard layouts

Comment: it looks like the Shift-Control-X tip works in the FF search box (as well as Gmail Chat). Excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key combination in Firefox 3 to switch from LTR/RTL is Control + Shift + X.  See [this support thread](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?locale=pl&comments_parentId=181049&forumId=1) from Mozilla for more details.

Comment: @Breakthrough, thank for the tip. This drives me crazy. Must happen when i'm using Ctrl-X to cut some text... Awesome, thanks again.